# How to get information for specific values within api

Tags: python, html, api

I can get the ticker symbols for all positions and the amount of all my positions but I want to be able to isolate specific stocks.

I have tried the code below and have been playing around with it, however I must at admit I struggle with the use of api.

```
wb=paper_webull()

webull_email='*********'


wb.login(webull_email, '*******')




positions = wb.get_positions('ticker': 'BTZ')

position_symbol = positions[0]["ticker"]["symbol"]

position_amount = positions[0]["position"]


print(positions)

print(position_symbol)
print(position_symboll)

print(position_amount)
```

output when positions=wb.get_position() instead of wb.get_positions('ticker': 'BTZ'):

```
[{'id': ******, 'accountId': *****, 'paperId': 1, 'ticker': {'tickerId': 913287017, 'symbol': 
'BTZ', 'name': 'BlackRock Credit Allocation Inc', 'tinyName': 'BlackRock Credit Allocation Inc', 
'listStatus': 1, 'exchangeCode': 'NYSE', 'exchangeId': 11, 'extType': [], 'type': 3, 'regionId': 6, 
'regionName': '美国', 'regionIsoCode': 'US', 'currencyId': 247, 'currencyCode': 'USD', 'secType': [2, 
11], 'exchangeTrade': True, 'disExchangeCode': 'NYSE', 'disSymbol': 'BTZ'}, 'status': 1, 'position': 
'100', 'cost': '1495', 'costPrice': '14.950', 'currency': 'USD', 'lastPrice': '14.92', 'marketValue': 
'1492.00', 'unrealizedProfitLoss': '-3.00', 'unrealizedProfitLossRate': '-0.0020', 'lotSize': 1}]
BTZ
100
```

Comment: not sure where the struggle is?  you can put `wb.get_positions('ticker': 'BTZ')` in loop and change 'BTZ' in loop i.e hardcoded 'BTZ' vs you can keep a variable there, and for value, you already figured out that you can get it by`positions[0]["position"]` .

Comment: the struggle is that wb.get_positions('ticker' : 'BTZ') does not work. But wb.getpositions() does work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edited:

https://github.com/tedchou12/webull

Checking against the webull github, the following is the function being discussed:

```
    def get_positions(self):
        ''' Current positions in paper trading account. '''
        return self.get_account()['positions']
```

The function doesn't accept any parameters which is why it won't work when you try calling `wb.get_positions(ticker="BTZ")`

What you are probably thinking of is the get_ticker() function:

```
    def get_ticker(self, stock=''):
        '''
        Lookup ticker_id
        Ticker issue, will attempt to find an exact match, if none is found, match the first one
        '''
        headers = self.build_req_headers()
        ticker_id = 0
        if stock and isinstance(stock, str):
            response = requests.get(self._urls.stock_id(stock, self._region_code), headers=headers)
            result = response.json()
            if result.get('data') :
                for item in result['data'] : # implies multiple tickers, but only assigns last one?
                    if 'symbol' in item and item['symbol'] == stock :
                        ticker_id = item['tickerId']
                        break
                    elif 'disSymbol' in item and item['disSymbol'] == stock :
                        ticker_id = item['tickerId']
                        break
                if ticker_id == 0 :
                    ticker_id = result['data'][0]['tickerId']
            else:
                raise ValueError('TickerId could not be found for stock {}'.format(stock))
        else:
            raise ValueError('Stock symbol is required')
        return ticker_id
```

You should be able to call this with: `wb.get_ticker("BTZ")` This will give you the ID for that ticker in the data obtained from `wb.get_positions()`. You would then need to loop through the returned data to pull out the information that you want.

As you would need to loop through it anyway, might as well cut out the get_ticker() step and manually check against the symbol in the first place.

The following code is all untested but should at least point you in the right direction.

```
# Assuming you have a number of symbols, add them to a list
itemsofinterest = ["BTZ","XYZ"]

# Get the dataset that you want to check
positions = wb.get_positions()

# Loop through the dataset
for position in positions:
  # Check if the current item matches anything in your list of items of interest
  if position['ticker']['symbol'] in itemsofinterest:
    # Print out some information or whatever you intend to do with it
    print(position['ticker']['symbol'])
    print(position['position'])
```

Comment: That did not work unfortunately. The output gives me what I want for all the positions I am in its just extracting the individual positions

Comment: @Josh-Murphy Completely changed the answer based on checking what I believe is the right github code!